# The minimum php version required to install Laravel

Tags: php, windows, laravel, windows-8, installation

What's the minimum php version required to install Laravel? According to this [wikihow](http://www.wikihow.com/Install-Laravel-Framework-in-Windows) tutorial, the minimum version required is 6.3.7:

> Install Laravel Framework in Windows *PHP version greater than 6.3.7 is required.

But the latest php version that can be installed with [xampp](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html) is 5.6.3. If a grater version is required, how can I install it?

Comment: Wow they are from the future

Comment: Given that PHP version 6 will __never__ exist, perhaps wikihow is wrong

Comment: @MarkBaker but only *perhaps* :D

Comment: @lukasgeiter - it could be that the interweb has somehow connected to a wikihow from a parallel universe where the original PHP6 actually worked and was released, and so it's the current version in that reality

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wikihow is wrong. The requirements for Laravel 4.2 are:

- PHP >= 5.4
- MCrypt PHP Extension

[Laravel Docs](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/installation#server-requirements)

---

By the way, for Laravel 5, the (not final) [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/master/installation#server-requirements) states:

- PHP >= 5.4
- Mcrypt PHP Extension
- OpenSSL PHP Extension
- Mbstring PHP Extension